# Kernel compile with builtroot and run it in qemu vm: fail to add MMCONFIG information

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu

I found a nice [tutorial on Linux kernel debugging](https://github.com/Rhydon1337/linux-kernel-debugging) with gdb + qemu + vscode. The big advantage would be, that I can use my familiar IDE vscode for kernel debugging.

The first step in the tutorial is to compile the kernel using builtroot and then run it in a qemu vm.

I get stuck at part 9. running the qemu vm.

This is the command from the tutorial:

```
sudo ~/Downloads/qemu-7.1.0/bin/debug/native/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 
-enable-kvm -cpu host -s -kernel bzImage -m 2048 
-hda rootfs.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda rw nokaslr" 
-net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

In the output window it shows:

```
acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ASPM ClockPM Segments HPX-Type3
acpi PNP0A03:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can’t access 
extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.PCI host bridge to
 bus 0000:00
```

[Screenshot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zIM6.jpg)

What even more confuses me is, I tried to adjust the command to print the qemu console to my terminal, such that I can read the full log.

```
sudo ~/Downloads/qemu-7.1.0/bin/debug/native/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 
-enable-kvm -cpu host -s -kernel bzImage -m 2048 
-hda rootfs.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda rw nokaslr console=ttyS0" 
-nographic -serial mon:stdio -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Then there is surprisingly no error message, but whatever command I type into the console, when I hit enter, the vm doesn't react, nothing happens.

[Full log pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EFgnrAny)

Host:
Ubuntu Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Linux 5.15.0-52
qemu 7.1.0
buildroot-2022.08

Guest:
Linux Kernel downloaded by builtroot: 5.15.18